# Unable to connect to MongoDb (using authentication) using mongocsharpdriver 2.7.0

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker, asp.net-core-2.0, mongodb-.net-driver

I have created a sample c# console application to connect to mongodb hosted on CentOS machine on a docker.

The command used to create container is below:

> docker run -d --name mongodb-container -p 2020:27017 -v /home/mongodb_data:/var/lib/mongodb/data -v /home/mongodb_log:/var/log/mongodb -v /home/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mongo

System IP: 172.17.103.158
Mongodb docker port: 2020

Now coming to c# code

```
class users
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

MongoContext Class

```
public class MongoContext
    {
        IMongoClient _client;
        public readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

        public MongoContext()
        {
            MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoUsername"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPassword"]);

            var settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Credential = credential,
                VerifySslCertificate = false,
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet,
                ReplicaSetName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"],
                UseSsl = false,
                Server = new MongoServerAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoHost"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPort"]))
            };

            _client = new MongoClient(settings);
            _database = _client.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"]);
        }
    }
```

Web Config:

```
<configuration>


<appSettings>
    <add key="MongoDatabaseName" value="clientdb" />
    <add key="MongoUsername" value="mongoadmin" />
    <add key="MongoPassword" value="secret" />
    <add key="MongoPort" value="2020" />
    <add key="MongoHost" value="172.17.103.158" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Viewing Users

```
static List<users> ViewUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            MongoContext db = new MongoContext();
            IMongoCollection<users> Table1 = db._database.GetCollection<users>("users");

            return Table1.AsQueryable().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }
```

Error:

```
{"A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{
  Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
    AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }.
Client view of cluster state is {
  ClusterId : \"1\",
  ConnectionMode : \"Automatic\",
  Type : \"Unknown\",
  State : \"Disconnected\",
  Servers : [{
    ServerId: \"{
      ClusterId : 1,
      EndPoint : \"172.17.103.158:2020\" }\",
    EndPoint: \"172.17.103.158:2020\",
    State: \"Disconnected\",
    Type: \"Unknown\",
    HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. 
        ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. 
        ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.<AuthenticateAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.SaslAuthenticator.<AuthenticateAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.DefaultAuthenticator.<AuthenticateAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.<AuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   
      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()\" }] }."}
```

In Short Error Message:

```
{"A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{
  Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
    AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }.
Client view of cluster state is {
  ClusterId : \"1\",
  ConnectionMode : \"Automatic\",
  Type : \"Unknown\",
  State : \"Disconnected\",
  Servers : [{
    ServerId: \"{
      ClusterId : 1,
      EndPoint : \"172.17.103.158:2020\" }\",
    EndPoint: \"172.17.103.158:2020\",
    State: \"Disconnected\",
    Type: \"Unknown\",
    HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. 
      ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. 
      ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..
```

I am facing this issue when mongo db is being protect by username and password otherwise not.

Altough MongoDb Compass is still able to connect to mongo db in both the cases.

**My Question is** : Why c# code is not getting connecting to mongodb when authentication is applied on db.

Solutions Tried:

1. Connected using uri:

   ```
   mongodb://mongoadmin:secret@172.17.103.158:2020/clientdb
   ```
2. Edited `mongod.config` => `BindIp 127.0.0.1, 172.17.103.17` (My system IP)
3. Using SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow this link [Mongo Site](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/reference/driver/connecting/)
and look at Section

> The Database Component : 
>   The database component is optional and is used to indicate which database to authenticate against. When the database component is not provided, the “admin” database is used.

The issue is you are authenticating the mongoadmin user for clientdb. But mongoadmin user is authenticated to admin db. Get the mongoadmin user authenticated and then you can access clientdb.

Below is the sample using URI method:

```
        IMongoClient _client;
        public readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

        public MongoContext_URIBased()
        {
            var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl("mongodb://mongoadmin:secret@172.17.103.158:2020/admin");
            _client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
            _database = _client.GetDatabase("clientdb");
        }
```

And According to your code , below will work:

Your config file should be like:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="MongoMasterDatabaseName" value="admin" />
<add key="MongoUsername" value="mongoadmin" />
<add key="MongoPassword" value="secret" />
<add key="MongoPort" value="2020" />
<add key="MongoHost" value="172.17.103.158" />
<add key="MongoClientDatabaseName" value="clientDb" />


</appSettings>
```

And C# code :

```
public class MongoContext
    {
        IMongoClient _client;
        public readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

        public MongoContext()
        {
            MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoMasterDatabaseName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoUsername"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPassword"]);
            var settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Credential = credential,
                Server = new MongoServerAddress(, Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPort"]))
            };
            _client = new MongoClient(settings);
            _database = _client.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoClientDatabaseName"]);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, mongoadmin user is getting authenticated to admin db first. Then you can connect to clientdb

Comment: Ok, let me try it

Answer (score 1):

in mongod.conf add your local ip to bind_ip

- mongod.conf File

  bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.xxx.xxxx

where:

- 127.0.0.1 to allow connection from same machine
- 192.168.xxx.xxxx to allow connection from this ip

[Check This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/problems-with-remote-connection-to-my-mongodb-server)

Make sure the username you are using is exist in  `clientdb` database

to add user to  `clientdb` database you can user following

```
use clientdb

db.createUser(
   {
     user: "mongoadmin",
     pwd: "secret",
     roles:
       [
         { role: "root", db: "admin" }
       ]
   }
)
```

Comment: Am I to understand that the database binds to 0.0.0.0 by default, but if you use a username/password then you need to be explicit about the IP addresses it's bound to?

Comment: Can you clarify if that's what your answer is (indirectly) stating?

Comment: i think he will not face this problem if he tried to connect to mongo-db locally

Comment: So, OP's database is running in a Docker container so it's never really "local". In the question, it says that it works without a username and password, but when one is used the above issue starts happening, hence my question re your answer.

Comment: you are right ,just updated my answer please check it

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem, I have already tried Bind IP Option which is not working in my case.. However, I am trying creating the user and will update soon on that..

Comment: Maybe he meant that you only forgot the role of the user?

Comment: you need to provide authentication database name in your web Config file.