# Unable to connect ot local mongoDb docker database

Tags: mongodb, docker, .net-core

I have a problem connecting to a mongoDb from my dotnet core 3.1 application.
Both the mongoDb and the API application is running inside container. Every container can be reached from the localhost and they are using the default docker network settings.

My mongoDb docker-compose file

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  mongoDatabase:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootPassword
    volumes:
      - ./mongoDatabase:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

My application docker-compose file

```
writer.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}writerapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Writer/Writer.API/Dockerfile
    environment:
        - MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb://root:rootPassword@host.docker.internal:27017/NewsGroup
        - MONGODB_DATABASE="NewsGroup"
        - MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME="News"
    ports:
        - "10020:80"
```

The reason behind both of them are in a compose file is that there are more services running inside that compose.

My code is following the [Microsoft offered mongodb docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). And the code is the following:

```
public class MongoDatabaseService : IMongoDatabaseService
    {
        private IMongoDatabase _context;
        private IMongoCollection<ArticleGroup> _articleGroup;

        public MongoDatabaseService()
        {
            string mongoConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_CONNECTION");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mongoConnectionString))
            {
                throw new Exception("MongoConnectionstring is empty");
            }

            string mongoDatabase = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_DATABASE");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mongoDatabase))
            {
                throw new Exception("MongoDatabase name is empty");
            }
            var client = new MongoClient(mongoConnectionString);
            _context = client.GetDatabase(mongoDatabase);

            string collectionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mongoDatabase))
            {
                throw new Exception("MongoDatabase collection is empty");
            }
            _articleGroup = _context.GetCollection<ArticleGroup>(collectionName);
        }

        public void AddArticleGroup(ArticleGroup newGroup)
        {
            _articleGroup.InsertOne(newGroup);
        }
    }
```

During the insert operation, I get the following exception

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: 'Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.'
MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..
```

I have also a visual client installed to see the actual actions and I can confirm that the database/collections specified are existing and accessible by the user.

[image]

Does anybody know what can be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Right now what I see in the visual client is the created NewsGroup. By default there were 3 database on creation time. Admin,config and local name database

Comment: I have changed the connectiostring to the above one. But now I get Command insert failed: Invalid namespace specified '"NewsGroup"."News"'.'

Comment: Try this: `MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb://root:rootPassword@host.docker.internal:27017/NewsGroup?authSource=admin` otherwise I don't know (may be related to the particular configuration)

Comment: Still the invalid namespace error :(

Comment: Maybe [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756773/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-using-authentication-using-mongocsharpdriver-2-7). I've cleaned up comments. Also, [compared to this](https://medium.com/faun/managing-mongodb-on-docker-with-docker-compose-26bf8a0bbae3) file the MDB docker compose is missing a line

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts..

### Service Name:

mongoDatabase

Shouldn't this be part of your connection string?

### MONGODB_DATABASE

The dockerfile for mongo database should have some kind of db init script that creates a database `NewsGroup`

### Restart Policy:

I guess the two services spin off almost at the same time
Web API is easy and probably gets there sooner.
MongoDB is taking a little longer.
the WebAPI has already crashed by then.
A dirty trick is to add a restart policy inside  docker-compose of `writer.api`

`restart: on-failure`

A better way to is to write a script in Dockerfile for writer API that'll make it wait for the `mongodbService` to come up

## Edits #1:

### Custom Network across different services:

```
...
  movieapi:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
    depends_on:
      - moviedb
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: ${MVCMOVIE_API_1_IP}
...
networks:
  public_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: ${NETWORK_SUBNET}
...
```

.env file:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=app_name
 
MVCMOVIE_EXPOSED_PORT=80
 
MVCMOVIE_API_1_IP=192.168.0.10
MVCMOVIE_WEB_1_IP=192.168.0.20
MVCMOVIE_WEB_2_IP=192.168.0.21
MVCMOVIE_DB_1_IP=192.168.0.30

HA_PROXY_IP=192.168.0.99

NETWORK_SUBNET=192.168.0.0/24
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. What i did is that I have two compose files. One compose file for all the database needed(mysql,mongodb,etc.) Right now I try to do everything manually to see what I have to automate later :D. What I do is that start the database composer and I wait manually for it to startup. And then later I start the api so the restart policy cannot be the problem. And I know about the starup script feature of mongodb but as I said I created the user/database/permissions manually with use NewsGroup (create database) db.createColllection() and db.createUser()

Comment: btw to `docker-compose.yml` mean two docker networks.. if you want these two files to be on the same network you need one docker compose or you need one network explicitly defined. Adding additional notes to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I added an extra "" around the environment variable, therefore it was looking for '"NewsGroup"' database which is non existent. After I had removed the extra "" is is working as expected.

So the final docker environment variable is

```
writer.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}writerapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Writer/Writer.API/Dockerfile
    environment:
        - MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb://root:rootPassword@host.docker.internal:27017/NewsGroup
        - MONGODB_DATABASE=NewsGroup
        - MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME=News
    ports:
        - "10020:80"
```